# gtm fb pixel code showing on web page

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager

does anyone know what the problem could be to cause the facebook pixel code to show on the webpages of the site when the code is placed in google tag manager? I've place the gtm code in the head and body as instructed. I'm noticing this code at the bottom of each page of the website: 
fbq('track', 'ViewContent'); fbq('track', 'Lead', { value: 5.00, currency: 'USD' }

Is there a way to keep this from showing?

Comment: You most likely used a custom html tag and forgot to wrap the fb script in </script>-Tags. At least that is what you should check first.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've doubled and tripled check that and all things are wrapped properly on site and gtm.

Comment: < script > fbq('track', 'Lead', { value: 5.00, currency: 'USD' } < /script> is how it is in gtm. The 'ViewContent' doesn't show anymore (could've been a cookie issue after refreshing?) This other one still shows on the pages though; not sure what I'm missing

Comment: If that's not an artifact of your example then you might try to remove the whitespace in your opening script tag. It should really not make any difference, but since we are both out of ideas you might as well try if it helps.

Comment: Found it! After I put the code in here and looked over it carefully, I noticed the spaces on script and /script! THAT was the reason. I removed the spaces and now it doesn't show on the bottom of the pages anymore. Thanks Eike Pierstorff for your suggestion to check over it all again!

Comment: LOL. Oh how funny! when I submitted my comment, yours popped in too! Great minds! Thanks so much again! Yep, you are right!

Comment: This is a recurring problem for tag implementers. Thanks for putting the question in.